# Dealing with complex objects

Tags: c#

I'm relatively new to C# programming and have had my first encounter with objects. A method that I am using is returning an object and I am setting it to an object of my own as such,

```
object target = searchResponse.Result.Parameters.Values;
```

From here I'm attempting to extract the data from the object, but it seems to be a "complex" object (just came up with that terminology, it's probably wrong, but I don't know the correct term). According to the Visual Studio locals menu, the object's value is `count = 2`. But, 'inside' the object is the data that I want, as shown below:

[image]

How would I get to these pieces of data?

Comment: Don't use `object` - that's the wrong approach here. If you aren't sure what the type is use `var` and let the compiler figure it out. And that image shows that `target` is a `Dictionary`, you can easily look up how to work with those in the documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What is the type of `searchResponse`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @UnholySheep suggested use `var` wherever possible if you don't know the `DataType` beforehand.

But for instance as you have stored the data in `target` and as in the picture it's of type `Dictionary`, you can cast it

```
Dictionary<string, object> dict = target as Dictionary<string, object>;
```

Now you can access your data from `dict`

**EDIT 1:**

I assumed you may want to know how to access data from a `Dictionary`, so here is a short snippet:

```
Dictionary<int, string> myDictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
//here _int_ will be the key, _string_ will be your data
myDictionary.Add(1, "abc");  //1 is key, abc is data
myDictionary.Add(2, "def");
myDictionary.Add(3, "ghk");

string myData = myDictionary[2]; //pass the value to be fetched
//myData = def
```

Comment: Why don't downvoter's leave a comment as reason when downvoting!??